# How to merge array with value sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry this is basic things but I dont know java-script array

I have simple array with same number of index and `n` number of array, If index have no value it will be `null`

```
Array [
        0: Array [ null, 10222, 10222, null,9999 ]
        1: Array [ 1870963, 1845801, 1830263, null, null ]
        2: Array [ 1870963, 1845801, 1830263, null, null ]
        n: Array [ n, n, n, n, n ]
    ];
```

So I need to make in in single array with sum just like below.

```
Array [3741926,3701824,3670748,0,9999];
```

Just need to make sum and into single array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the array with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and sum each column using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var arr = [
  [null, 10222, 10222, null, 9999],
  [1870963, 1845801, 1830263, null, null],
  [1870963, 1845801, 1830263, null, null],
];

var result = arr[0].map(function(a, i) {
  return arr.reduce(function(s, n) {
    return s + n[i];
  }, 0);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` like so:

```js
const a = [
        [ null, 10222, 10222, null,9999 ],
        [ 1870963, 1845801, 1830263, null, null ],
        [ 1870963, 1845801, 1830263, null, null ]
    ];
    
console.log(a.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.map((x, i) => x + cur[i])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.prototype.map` and  `array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
var arr = [
  [ null, 10222, 10222, null,9999 ],
  [ 1870963, 1845801, 1830263, null, null ],
  [ 1870963, 1845801, 1830263, null, null ]
];

var result = arr[0].map((_, i) => arr.reduce((m, e) => m + e[i], 0));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Look at the output the OP wants. It's the sum of each array's _n_ index.

Comment: @AnkitSoni I've fixed

Comment: Your `row` variable in `map()` method is misleading. It won't keep "row", but the element from first array.

Comment: @EganWolf Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` with `array#foreach`.

```js
var arr = [ [ null, 10222, 10222, null,9999 ],[ 1870963, 1845801, 1830263, null, null ],[ 1870963, 1845801, 1830263, null, null ],[ null, null, null, null, null ]];
var result = arr.reduce((r,a,j) => {
  a.forEach((v,i) => {
    r[i] = (r[i]||0) + (v||0); 
  });
  return r;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```